¿Por qué me sale ERROR 303: Subindice (0) fuera de rango (1...7) al ejecutar el programa?
Necesito ayuda por favor...
Tengo que ordenar una lista de números de menor a mayor, con el método de la burbuja y al momento de ejecutar el programa me marca un error.
en la línea 12.
esta es la línea que marca error.
 si lista[i] > lista[j-1] Entonces

También en la línea 10, no me deja colocar "lista"
Me lo marca igual, como error.
línea 10:
n = Longitud(list);

Algoritmo burbuja_orden 
    Dimension lista[7];
    lista[1]=3;
    lista[2]=9;
    lista[3]=6;
    lista[4]=12;
    lista[5]=1;
    lista[6]=0;
    lista[7]=10;
    n = Longitud(list);
    Para i Desde 0 Hasta n-1
        si lista[i] > lista[j-1] Entonces
            Temp = lista[i]
            lista[i] = lista[j-1]
            lista[j-1] = Temp
            
        FinSi
    FinPara
FinAlgoritmo


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! y que es j???
